# Adding multiple definitions for a single key

Tags: swift

Ok, say I have a dictionary:

`var someDict = [String: String]()`

I can add a key and definition to it with:

`someDict["Smiling"] = ":)`

But let's say I want to add another definition to `"Smiling"`, such as `:D`.

`someDict["Smiling"]? += ":D"`

```
print(someDict)
["Smiling": ":):D"]
```

Now I want is

`["Smiling": ":)", ":D"]`. I know this won't work, because of the `,` seperator.

So I need a way to use `["Smiling": [":)", ":D"]]`, that way I could access it with `someDict["Smiling"][1]`, and that would equal `:D`.

I won't list want I have tried, as it is all useless, and I don't know what I am doing.

To sum up,

I want to be able to add a key in a dictionary, potentially in a for loop.

Comment: You're right, you need `[String : [String]]`, and that will work, but you need to tell us what's wrong with using `someDict["Smiling"]?.first`, `someDict["Smiling"]?.last`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

All you should need is this type of data format:

```
var someDict = [String: [String]]()
```

Initialize it:

```
someDict["Smiling"] = [":)"]
```

That way you can do this:

```
someDict["Smiling"]?.append(":D")
```

And call it:

```
someDict["Smiling"]?[1] //returns ":D"
```

**Edit**:

It's probably worth mentioning that as @dfri stated, using the explicit array index call ("[1]") is unsafe because this will fail if your array doesn't have two or more values. One "Swifty" solution is to make your invalidated index validated through checking that it is in the array.

This could look something like this (thanks to @Hamish for the code):

```
let idx = 1

if let arr = someDict["Smiling"], arr.indices.contains(idx) {
    print(arr[idx]) // :D
}
```

Comment: None of the two last code line will compile. Access to a dictionary value by key yields an optional, so you need to unwrap this prior to mutating it (e.g. using optional binding, `someDict["Smiling"]?.append(":D")` & `someDict["Smiling"]?[1]`). Note that the latter explicit access by index is unsafe, as it will lead to a runtime exception in case of index out of bounds.

Comment: @dfri Sorry overlooked that. It is fixed now.

Comment: @dfri For your second point about it being unsafe, how could I improve that? Would checking the array's length before calling that be a good idea?

Comment: Checking the array length is one approach, which a "Classic C/C++" array length validation prior to access by index. Another more Swifty approach would be e.g. using the [`index(_:offsetBy:limitedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1782899-index) method of `Array` to create a safe index from an "unsafe" (non-validated) one; [e.g. as in this gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/961c8bd13cc3a47cb5972c7cccf57d8f). In your example, index `1` is the same as the last valid index though, so simply using the optional `last` property would probably be the best alternative.

Comment: @dfri Oh okay, that's cool I haven't seen that before. I have updated my answer to reflect this method :)

Comment: Happy to help :) note also that I slightly edited the `index` call (as I slightly edited the gist, but probably after you read it: the limit should be `endIndex - 1`, not `endIndex` as I first wrote, as `endIndex` itself is out of bounds!).

Comment: @dfri Aha well that's an important difference :D

Comment: @dfri I don't believe that will work for an empty array, as the limit has no effect if it is less than the starting index (and the offset is positive) – thus for an empty array, `array.endIndex - 1` will be `-1` and therefore have no effect. Simpler solution would just be `array.indices.contains(index)`, or just a plain old `count` check.

Comment: @Hamish ah, thanks, I believed the `limitedBy` was using a strict less than condition, but as you (and the docs) say, _"If `n > 0`, limit has no effect if it is less than `i`."_

Comment: @Hamish anecdote: as expected the same holds for the [`formIndex(_:offsetBy:limitedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1782284-formindex) method, but curiously the docs for this method does not mention that the limit has no effect when being less than the supplied `i` index (first arg) (it doesn't, in fact, even given a description of its third parameter `limit`).

Comment: @dfri Huh, that is curious – looks like just an oversight (might even be worth filing a bug over, given that the behaviour is somewhat non-obvious).

Comment: @Hamish I believe the lang. docs are autogenerated from the source, right? So I might just create a pull request updating the description of [this blueprint](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L292) and the description of [this implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1048). I don't really know the convention of bugs w.r.t. the language docs: file a bug and link to a pull request? (Since I might oversee something in fixing this myself).

Comment: @dfri I do indeed believe that the docs are autogenerated from the source. I cannot say I'm familiar at all with the process of making a change to it (I've only ever filed the occasional bug), but I agree in that filing a bug on the JIRA and linking to a pull request sounds like the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to wrap this up in a structure of your own. Exactly how you do it depends on the semantics you want, but consider something like this as a starting point:

```
struct MyDictArray {
    private var _data: [String : [String]] = [:]

    mutating func append(key: String, value: String) {
        if let existingEntry = self._data[key] {
            self._data[key] = existingEntry + [value]
        } else {
            self._data[key] =  [value]
        }
    }
    subscript(key: String) -> [String] {
        get {
            if let existingEntry = self._data[key] {
                return existingEntry
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }
        set {
            if let existingEntry = self._data[key] {
                self._data[key] = existingEntry + newValue
            } else {
                self._data[key] = newValue
            }
        }

    }
    subscript(key: String, index: Int) -> String? {
        if index < self[key].count {
            return self[key][index]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

var someDict = MyDictArray()
someDict["Smiling"] = [":)"]
someDict.append(key: "Smiling", value: "D")
someDict["Smiling"]
someDict["Smiling", 1] // Safe indexing
```